# HTML Canvas not showing on Safari

Tags: html, canvas, scroll

I'm using the code in the Codepen below in order to create a full-width canvas that simulates video playback on an image sequence on scroll.

It works fine in Chrome, but I can't manage to make it work on Safari – it simply appears white, as if it was empty. If I inspect the element, it seems to not exist in Safari.

Is there a known issue with that or something that can be fixed in the code?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/SalmanShaikh/pen/MWeNBLL

```js
const appleSequenceImages = [];
//number of images 131; fill the array
//see the squence obj below for image path.
for (let i = 0; i <= 374; i++) {
  console.log(`${`${i}`.slice(-4)}.jpg`);
  appleSequenceImages.push(`${`${i}`.slice(-4)}.jpg`);
}


const requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

class EventEmitter {
  listeners = {}
  addListener(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    this.listeners[eventName].push(fn);
    return this;
  }
  on(eventName, fn) {
    return this.addListener(eventName, fn);
  }
  once(eventName, fn) {
    this.listeners[eventName] = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    const onceWrapper = () => {
      fn();
      this.off(eventName, onceWrapper);
    }
    this.listeners[eventName].push(onceWrapper);
    return this;
  }
  off(eventName, fn) {
    return this.removeListener(eventName, fn);
  }
  removeListener(eventName, fn) {
    let lis = this.listeners[eventName];
    if (!lis) return this;
    for (let i = lis.length; i > 0; i--) {
      if (lis[i] === fn) {
        lis.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    return this;
  }
  emit(eventName, ...args) {
    let fns = this.listeners[eventName];
    if (!fns) return false;
    fns.forEach((f) => {
      f(...args);
    });
    return true;
  }
  listenerCount(eventName) {
    let fns = this.listeners[eventName] || [];
    return fns.length;
  }
  rawListeners(eventName) {
    return this.listeners[eventName];
  }
}
class Canvas {
  constructor(e) {
    this.images = e.images;
    this.container = e.container;
    this.cover = e.cover;
    this.displayIndex = 0;
  }

  setup() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.container.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.resize());
    this.resize();
  }

  renderIndex(e) {
    if (this.images[e]) {
      return this.drawImage(e);
    }
    // Find closest loaded image
    for (var t = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, r = e; r >= 0; r--)
      if (this.images[r]) {
        t = r;
        break
      }
    for (var n = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, i = e, o = this.images.length; i < o; i++)
      if (this.images[i]) {
        n = i;
        break
      }
    this.images[t] ? this.drawImage(t) : this.images[n] && this.drawImage(n)
  }

  drawImage(e) {
    this.displayIndex = e,
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    const x = Math.floor((this.canvas.width - this.images[this.displayIndex].naturalWidth) / 2);
    const y = Math.floor((this.canvas.height - this.images[this.displayIndex].naturalHeight) / 2);
    if (this.cover) {

      this.drawImageCover(this.ctx, this.images[this.displayIndex]);
    } else {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.images[this.displayIndex], x, y);
    }
  }

  resize() {
    const w = this.container.clientWidth;
    const h = this.container.clientHeight;
    this.canvas.style.height = `${h}px`;
    this.canvas.style.width = `${w}px`;
    this.canvas.height = h;
    this.canvas.width = w;

    this.renderIndex(this.displayIndex);
  }

  /**
   * Main code by Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen, modified by me.
   *
   * drawImageProp(context, image [, x, y, width, height [,offsetX, offsetY]])
   *
   * If image and context are only arguments rectangle will equal canvas
   */
  drawImageCover(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      x = y = 0;
      w = ctx.canvas.width;
      h = ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    // default offset is center
    offsetX = typeof offsetX === "number" ? offsetX : 0.5;
    offsetY = typeof offsetY === "number" ? offsetY : 0.5;

    // keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
    if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
    if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
    if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;
    //added new prop.width and height for precise movement
    var iw = img.width,
      ih = img.height,
      r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
      nw = iw * r, // new prop. width
      nh = ih * r, // new prop. height
      cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    // decide which gap to fill
    if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;
    if (Math.abs(ar - 1) < 1e-14 && nh < h) ar = h / nh; // updated
    nw *= ar;
    nh *= ar;

    // calc source rectangle
    cw = iw / (nw / w);
    ch = ih / (nh / h);

    cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
    cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

    // make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
    if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
    if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
    if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

    // fill image in dest. rectangle
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch, x, y, w, h);
  }
}
class ImgLoader extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(opts) {
    super();
    this.images = opts.imgsRef;
    this.imageNames = opts.images;
    this.imagesRoot = opts.imagesRoot;
    this.sequenceLength = opts.images.length;
    this.priorityFranes = opts.priorityFrames;
    this.complete = false;
    this.loadIndex = 0;

    this.priorityQueue = this.createPriorityQueue();
    this.loadingQueue = this.createLoadingQueue();

    this.loadNextImage();
  }

  loadImage(e) {
    if (this.images[e]) {
      return this.loadNextImage();
    }
    const onLoad = () => {
      img.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
      this.images[e] = img;

      if (e === 0) {
        this.emit('FIRST_IMAGE_LOADED');
      }
      this.loadNextImage();
    }
    const img = new Image;
    img.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    img.src = (this.imagesRoot ? this.imagesRoot : '') + this.imageNames[e];
  }

  loadNextImage() {
    if (this.priorityQueue.length) {
      this.loadImage(this.priorityQueue.shift());
      if (!this.priorityQueue.length) {
        this.emit('PRIORITY_IMAGES_LOADED');
      }
    } else if (this.loadingQueue.length) {
      this.loadImage(this.loadingQueue.shift())
    } else {
      this.complete = true;
      this.emit('IMAGES_LOADED');
    }
  }

  createPriorityQueue() {
    const p = this.priorityFrames || [];
    if (!p.length) {
      p.push(0);
      p.push(Math.round(this.sequenceLength / 2));
      p.push(this.sequenceLength - 1);
    }
    return p;
  }

  createLoadingQueue() {
    return this.imageNames.map((s, i) => i).sort((e, n) => {
      return Math.abs(e - this.sequenceLength / 2) - Math.abs(n - this.sequenceLength / 2)
    });
  }
}
class ScrollSequence {
  constructor(opts) {
    this.opts = {
      container: 'body',
      starts: 'out',
      ends: 'out',
      imagesRoot: '',
      cover: false,
      ...opts
    }
    this.container = typeof opts.container === 'object' ?
      opts.container :
      document.querySelector(opts.container);

    this.scrollWith = !opts.scrollWith ?
      this.container :
      typeof opts.scrollWith === 'object' ?
      opts.scrollWith :
      document.querySelector(opts.scrollWith);

    this.images = Array(opts.images.length);
    this.imagesToLoad = opts.images;
    this.priorityFrames = opts.priorityFrames;

    this.loader = new ImgLoader({
      imgsRef: this.images,
      images: this.imagesToLoad,
      imagesRoot: this.opts.imagesRoot,
      priorityFrames: this.priorityFrames
    });

    this.canvas = new Canvas({
      container: this.container,
      images: this.images,
      cover: this.opts.cover
    });

    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.canvas.setup();
    this.loader.once('FIRST_IMAGE_LOADED', () => {
      this.canvas.renderIndex(0);
    })
    this.loader.once('PRIORITY_IMAGES_LOADED', () => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.changeOnWindowScroll());
    })
    this.loader.once('IMAGES_LOADED', () => {
      console.log('Sequence Loaded');
    })
  }

  changeOnWindowScroll() {
    const step = 100 / (this.images.length - 1);
    const mapToIndex = Math.floor(this.percentScrolled / step);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.canvas.renderIndex(mapToIndex));
  }

  get percentScrolled() {
    const {
      starts,
      ends
    } = this.opts;
    const el = this.scrollWith;
    const doc = document.documentElement;
    const clientOffsety = doc.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset;
    const elementHeight = el.clientHeight || el.offsetHeight;
    const clientHeight = doc.clientHeight;
    let target = el;
    let offsetY = 0;
    do {
      offsetY += target.offsetTop;
      target = target.offsetParent;
    } while (target && target !== window);

    let u = (clientOffsety - offsetY);
    let d = (elementHeight + clientHeight)

    if (starts === 'out') u += clientHeight;
    if (ends === 'in') d -= clientHeight;
    if (starts == 'in') d -= clientHeight;

    const value = u / d * 100;
    return value > 100 ? 100 : value < 0 ? 0 : value;
  }
}

const appleSequence = new ScrollSequence({
container: '.apple-sequence',
scrollWith: '.apple-container',
images: appleSequenceImages,
imagesRoot: 'https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/02-head-bob-turn/',
priorityFrames: [0],
cover: true,
playUntil: 'scroll-out',
starts: 'in'
});

// END SCROLL_SEQUENCE CODE

});
```

Comment: Do you get any console messages/errors?

Comment: Warning: your codepen takes a LOT of memory

Comment: it is working fine for me, what version of Safari you are using.?

Comment: I just tested it and it works on safari version: Versjon 15.0 (16612.1.29.41.4, 16612). Safari versions older than 7 do not support `requestAnimationFrame` and other animations, so you better check Safari version.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your code on Safari, it works fine for me. I checked even in the console and there isn't any error, just the image names that get loaded.

Try to clean your cache and check again. If you get the same result, try with Safari Preview

Safari version used: 14.1.2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30009424)